# #+ATTR_LATEX as result of macro expansion in org-mode latex export

Tags: export, org-mode

I'm trying to set up a `#+ATTR_LATEX` statement, as a result of a macro, but it's no working. This is a MWE:

```
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil
#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [11pt,a4paper]
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{float}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{booktabs}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{tabu}

#+MACRO: tabdef :placement [t] :center t :booktabs t :environment tabu :width \textwidth :align $1

This works:

#+CAPTION: Test caption 1
#+NAME: tab:test1
#+ATTR_LATEX: :placement [t] :center t :booktabs t :environment tabu :width \textwidth :align X[1lm]X[2lm]
|------------+----------------|
| *Heading1* | *Heading2*     |
|------------+----------------|
|       1234 | Lorem Ipsum    |
|       5678 | dolor sit amet |
|------------+----------------|


And this doesn't


#+CAPTION: Test caption 2
#+NAME: tab:test2
#+ATTR_LATEX: {{{tabdef(X[1lm]X[2lm])}}}
|------------+----------------|
| *Heading1* | *Heading2*     |
|------------+----------------|
|       1234 | Lorem Ipsum    |
|       5678 | dolor sit amet |
|------------+----------------|
```

For the second LaTeX block, org-mode exporter doesn't appropriate translate table settings; i.e, is not correctly expanding `{{{tabdef}}}` macro. This is the corresponding LaTeX output;

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{\label{tab:org4671fb8}Test caption 2}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rl}
\hline
\textbf{Heading1} & \textbf{Heading2}\\
\hline
1234 & Lorem Ipsum\\
5678 & dolor sit amet\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I also tried define the whole `#+attr_latex` line as:

```
#+MACRO: tabdef "#+ATTR_LATEX: :placement [t] :center t :booktabs t :environment tabu :width \textwidth :align $1"
```

whith the same result.

I'm writing a document with lot of such tables, using same definitions, only changing the `:align` parameter. It should be great to find a way to automatize this, with macros or maybe, elisp code.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** removed `#begin_table` and `#end_table` marks. Doesn't changes the problem but includes extra environments in latex outputs.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: Not yet, but haven't tried it too much...